# Fastest possible way to render 480 x 320 background as iPhone OpenGL ES textures

Tags: iphone, performance, graphics, opengl-es, textures

I need to display 480 x 320 background image in OpenGL ES. The thing is I experienced a bit of a slow down in iPhone when I use 512 x 512 texture size. So I am finding an optimum case for rendering iPhone resolution size background in OpenGL ES. How should I slice the background in this case to obtain the best possible performance? My main concern is speed. Should I go for 256 x 256 or other texture sizes here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, are you testing performance on the Simulator? If so, *stop immediately* and try it on actual hardware. **Performance testing on the simulator is worthless.**

With that out of the way, I'm not sure how many of these you've already implemented, so I apologize if I'm giving you what you already know:

- If you're drawing a fullscreen opaque background every frame, you may not need a `GL_CLEAR` call

  - gmaclachlan points out you should clear the buffers every run for performance reasons, however this is contrary to some other user experience. This may differ between hardware and iOS revisions; however, performance can be tested just by commenting out the line. Check before and after.
  - If you're using the Z-axis at all (ie: 3D objects over a 2D background, think *New Super Mario Bros*) you will want to clear the depth buffer
- Use texture compression (PVRTC) if the compression artifacts aren't an
  issue, it's hardware accelerated
- Use a 16-bit texture for the background if you can't use PVRTC
- Make sure you're not trying to depth test/alpha blend the background if there's nothing under it
- Use the [OES_Draw_Texture](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt) extension if you're using
  fixed-function

  `int rect[4] = {0, 0, 480, 320};`
  `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texBackground);`
  `glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, rect);`
  `glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, z, 480, 320);`

Beyond that, try grabbing just that segment of your code and seeing just how many background per second it's capable of spitting out.

Comment: Just a note: it's always a good idea to use glClear() at the start of the frame (even if you're going to overwrite the frame entirely) on this hardware - it means that the driver knows no information needs to be kept from the previous frame and saves all the work involved in doing that.

Comment: Why would it save anything unless you specify kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking = YES? I tried testing (on HW) with Instruments, and found more utilisation using glClear than without.

Comment: @gmaclachlan, @v01d: what iOS versions and hardware were you using? I reached my GL_CLEAR conclusions with an original iPhone (lowest common denominator) and a target platform of 3.0.0. Since a glClear line is simple enough to comment/uncomment, it's worth testing both ways to see if it works. Also added a bit about the 3D-over-2D and the requirement to clear depth if that's in play.